# How to prevent redundant persistence calls from GWT RequestFactory context?

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, requestcontext

In a project of mine I have a GWT `EntityProxy` simplified as follows:

```
@ProxyFor(value = Item.class, locator = ItemService.class)
public interface ItemProxy extends EntityProxy
{
    String getName();

    // other getters and setters here
}
```

with a corresponding entity implementation that is a simple JPA annotated entity bean.

I also have a request context:

```
@Service(value = ItemService.class, locator = InjectingServiceLocator.class)
public interface ItemRequestContext extends RequestContext
{
    Request<List<ItemProxy>> findItems();
}
```

And the corresponding service and locator implementations:

```
public class ItemService extends Locator<Item, Long>
{
    @Override
    public Item find(Class<? extends Item> clazz, Long id)
    {
        return getItemFromJpa(id);
    }

    public List<Item> findItems()
    {
        return getAllItemsFromJpa();
    }

    // Remaining Locator and JPA methods skipped
}
```

When I invoke the `findItems` method in the GWT request context from the RPC perspective everything seems to work as expected and I get the items list in the callback method to work with in the client.

But from the persistence perspective the implementation does not work as expected: On the server side the method `findItems` is called as expected fetches my items from the persistence and returns them. Then for every single item the method `find` is called with the item's id and of course retrieves the items again from persistence one after each other.

What causes GWT request factory context to make these useless invocations and how can I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before returning to the browser, RequestFactory will check each and every domain object it saw (either from the request, or in the service methods' return value) to see whether it still exists or not, and thus determine whether it should tell the client that the object has been deleted (generate an `EntityProxyChange` event with `WriteOperation.DELETE`).

This check is done by calling the locator's `isLive` method, whose default implementation calls `find` with the object's ID and checks whether the return value is `null`.

In other words, you can simply override `isLive` in your locator to provide your own logic, and possibly bypass the call to the persistence layer.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me for entities send to the server from the client but questionable for entities just queried from the server to be sent to the client. I'll check your suggestion as soon as I can but I'll have the problem that I do not want to break saving of entities so I guess I'll have to distinguish between checks of incoming and outgoing entities somehow.

Comment: What I really miss from the GWT RequestFactory documentation is a doc for the workflow that is performed for a request regarding which data is transferred to the server, which locator/service methods are called in which order, which data is then returned to the client and which events are thrown on the client. Regarding this the different handling of EntityProxys and ValueProxys would be of special interest.

Comment: Something like that? http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryMovingParts#Flow

Comment: The case for checking each and every domain object is that you could do something like: `ctx.getFoo("id"); ctx.deleteFoo("id"); ctx.fire();` which would return the _foo_ to the client but also _fire_ the delete event.

Comment: Oh yes thats a good one! Don't know how I have missed that regarding the googeling done in the last few days :D Its quite informative about the flow for EntityProxies at least :)

Comment: ValueProxies are stripped-down versions of EntityProxies: always have a "synthetic stableId", don't have a version (skip version check), with() doesn't apply (all properties are always transmitted), as well as isLive. With a locator, only create() will ever be called.

Comment: Thanks for that additional Info :)

Comment: Thanks, overriding `isLive(...)` would do the trick. But maybe a better way to go would be to have the JPA entity manager return cached versions of the just retrieved items if this is possible.